# How to use correctly \expandafter? (real example with \uppercase)

Tags: expansion, expandafter

(This question is not related to LaTeX 3).

At https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/, I read this code:

```latex
\newcommand{\cmda}{abcd}
\uppercase{abcd\cmda}
```

This give "ABCDabcd".

The target is to obtain "ABCDABCD" with `\uppercase`.

And the author say (without solution) that using `\expandafter` will give the expected "ABCDABCD". I have searched at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/expandafter, then https://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf, and also https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/A_six-part_article_series_on_%5Cexpandafter%2C_TeX_tokens_and_expansion.

In order to avoid any confusion, I slightly change the example.

I begin with:

```latex
\newcommand{\cmda}{abcd}
\uppercase{efgh\cmda}
```

and will obtain "EFGHABCD".

I have tried a lot of combinaisons without any luck (I know this is not the good method, but what to do in desperate situations?).

I also searched a solution in https://ctan.org/pkg/apprendre-a-programmer-en-tex (`\expandafter` is treated at page 103 and after).

```latex
\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{efgh\cmda}
```

Don't work (gives "EFGHabcd").

If I'm less ambitious, and only try with "e\cmda", this code works :

```latex
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter e\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\cmda}
```

and gives : "EABCD". It works perhaps with less "\expandafter". Anyway, the answer seems to depend with the number of chars before "\cmda" in the argument of `\uppercase`).

If so, \expandafter is probably not the good solution to uppercasing "\cmda".

What is the methodic method to anwser the question with "e\cmda" in the argument of `\uppercase`, then with "efgh\cmda" in the argument, then with "\cmda" in the argument?

I'm very beginner in low level LaTeX, and this question is more a curiosity than a real problem.

Comment: expandafter will only work for commands at the begin: `\uppercase\expandafter{\cmda abcd\cmda}` will give `ABCDABCDabcd`. To reach something at the end you need lots of \expandafter (and need to know how much). What is the best depends a lot about the nature of your argument. If it is normal text, use \MakeUppercase.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, this clarify a lot of things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction

```
\uppercase\expandafter{<tokens>}
```

will just try to expand the first token after the `{` and in your case it will not touch `\cmda`. So with

```
\uppercase\expandafter{abcd\cmda}
```

the effect is exactly the same as doing

```
\uppercase{abcd\cmda}
```

Since TeX only uppercases explicit character tokens (using the `\uccode` table), you eventually get

> ABCDabcd

Adding `\expandafter` in front of `\uppercase` does nothing new (`\uppercase` performs macro expansion until finding `{`).

You can use “full” expansion (not with `tex` that hasn't `\expanded`)

```
\uppercase\expandafter{\expanded{abcd\cmda}}
```

otherwise you have to resort to

```
\uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter a\expandafter b\expandafter c\expandafter d\cmda}
```

Comment: Thanks, so `\expandafter` isn't the "magical" solution expected. In particular, as you demonstrate in your last code, it must be adapted for any particular situation (not the same if the argument of `uppercase` is "e\cmd" and "efgh\cmda" or more complex "\cmda efgh\cmda". I thought there was a generic solution, but not. I learn so a new thing here.

Comment: You should also probably say that `\uppercase` should not be used on user-supplied text as it breaks utf-8, and that `\MakeUppercase` would do the needed expansion (@quark67)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the recall. My question was essentially theoretical (in order to understand the \expandafter in the context exposed in the introduction to LaTeX 3 linked in the begin of my question), but it is very useful to recall the limitation of `\uppercase` in real situations, where using utf-8 characters are not theoretical ;).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess that the question was just about understanding the working of `\uppercase`. In real world applications it should never be used (except if you're in the AMS staff, of course).