how to obtain the first 30(or 50) char of a variable content
I try to explain in other way what I need.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
 \newcommand{\TaI}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla, bla bla, bla bla bla. Bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla.}
 \newcommand{TbI}{}
\begin{document}

\TaI
\end{document}

I have in TaI my first phrase (it could be more and more longer than example) I would put in the TbI variable just the first phrase (until the first dot).I have the dot as separator.
Is it possible? And if yes:how?
Thank you
Renato

Again, your code does not compile because of the same error as yesterday. Please test your code before you post a question. And please also fix the error in yesterday's post.

The listofitems package can parse between seperators, here specified as a ..
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{.}
 \newcommand{\TaI}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla, bla bla, bla bla bla. Bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla.}
\begin{document}
\readlist*\TbI{\TaI}
First segment is: \TbI[1].

Next segment is: \TbI[2].
\end{document}




More or less same as your previous question, but delimiting on .
\documentclass{article}
  \newcommand{\TaI}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla, bla bla, bla bla bla. Bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla.}
 \def\tmp#1.#2\tmp{#1}
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\TbI\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp\TaI\tmp}
\begin{document}

\TaI

\bigskip

\TbI

\end{document}


yes!!! both two do the thing I would!
thanks to all
Renato

also if I don't understand how does it works. Can you tell me what part of LaTeX do I have to learn?

@RenatoP several answers on this site will explain \expandafter eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671146/how-to-use-correctly-expandafter-real-example-with-uppercase   note that one of the main goals of the expl3 syntax you will see on this site is to avoid the need for chains of expandafter and use a simple argument specification like :V to cause the argument to be expanded, but it doesn't hurt to see the underlying tex primitive first.

sorry David, I've implemented it for 15 times and I receive an error. Do I have some limit (i.e. not more that 3). I can also send my main.tex

what do you mean for 15 times? the code I posted answers the question you asked, it grabs all the characters up to the first .  did you try the document I posted here? @RenatoP

I mean I repeat the code you do for 15 variable: AaI, AaII AaIII, AbI AbII etc since AeIII. if you tell there is no limit I watch the code I made, maybe there is a bug

@RenatoP oh you could do thousands of variables this way
